# How can I get the file directory with name in java

Tags: java, get, fileinfo

I need to get the application's directory with name. For example, if my java application is working at C:\Program Files\example1.exe I need to get it as "C:\Program Files\example1.exe". Or is it working at C:\Windows\example2.exe
I need to get it as "C:\Windows\example2.exe" . How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to find where is your working directory.

Comment: Thanks and how can I get the .jar's name.